# Transfer binary data via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have some binary data (stored as byte[]) that need to be transferred to the same App on an other device via bluetooth. The whole thing is a really simple 1:1 transfer between these two applications. Now I found a very long documentation of a complex procedure at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp that describes how to do that.

Since this is VERY complicated for the simple task I want to do: is there a library evailable that encapsulates all this and provides an easy to use interface for bluetooth data transfer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the documentation itself is a part of library. I have never seen any library combining all these. But if you feel these difficult to understand you can refer an android cookbook which contains sample codes for transfering data via bluetooth